# Find text and replace with index

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, find-and-replace

I need to find a string and replace it with a moving index (in this case find pattern is "replaceThis")

For example:

```
id=replaceThis
......
id=replaceThis
......
id=replaceThis
```

should become

```
id=0
......
id=1
......
id=2
```

My environment is windows (and notepad++) but I also have access to cygwin

Comment: See [so] question [Notepad++ incrementally replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7602816)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy in `awk` (in Cygwin):

```
awk '{ while ($0 ~ /replaceThis/) sub(/replaceThis/, counter++) } 1'
```

On each line, for as long as it contains the string you're looking for,
replace (one occurrence of) it with the value of the counter, which you then increment. 
The `1` at the end is a shorthand way of telling `awk` to print the line after it has replaced all occurrences (if any) of the string; you could just as well say

```
awk '{ while ($0 ~ /replaceThis/) sub(/replaceThis/, counter++); print }'
```

Comment: looks promising... will try and report back

Comment: works like a charm. Awk is quite cumbersome in syntax and usage. Any pointers to start learning?